# SQL | Получить количество данных из таблицы

Tags: sql

У меня есть данный SQL код

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_count_images`.`value` AS `count_images` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON 
(at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `at_count_images` ON 
(at_count_images.`entity_id`=e.entity_id) AND 
(at_count_images.attribute_id=77) WHERE (((`e`.`attribute_set_id` = '12') OR 
(`e`.`attribute_set_id` = '4'))) AND (at_qty.qty > 0)
```

Я хочу получить количество данных из таблицы `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` для каждого товара(к примеру, есть индификатор 3148, у меня 3 данных, я хочу чтобы мне count вернул 3. и так для каждого продукта)

Но когда я добавляю `count(at_count_images.value)` оно мне возвращает количество ВСЕХ данных (как показано на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы подсчитывало так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(entity_id),`e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_count_images`.`value` AS `count_images` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON 
(at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `at_count_images` ON 
(at_count_images.`entity_id`=e.entity_id) AND 
(at_count_images.attribute_id=77) WHERE (((`e`.`attribute_set_id` = '12') OR 
(`e`.`attribute_set_id` = '4'))) AND (at_qty.qty > 0) group by entity_id;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочтите вопрос ещё раз. Это не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: изменил запрос, проверяйте.

Comment: Спасибо! Из головы вылетело group by